# How do I start a new community for home repair (appliances, garage doors, roofs)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to start a new community, namely Household Repairs. Since becoming a home owner ten years ago, I have done about 20 - 30 repairs on wildly disparate devices that I didn't have a clue about when I started. There are plenty of sites that already do this kind of thing, but they are nowhere near as discipline or non-commercial as Stack. Help a brother out. How do I start a new community?

Answer (score 6):

You start a new site by [proposing it on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). Then other people need to commit to making the site a working possibility. When enough have signed on, Stack Exchange launches the site as a "beta".

In this case, though, there's already a site that sounds like it fits your needs: the [Home Improvement SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com). Their [help page about what's on topic says this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Questions you would typically ask a home contractor.**
>   • Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task.
>   • Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home.
>   • National building codes (of any country).
>   • Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances.
>   • Carpentry and woodworking.